# Creating a KeyDown Event Handler for the Label Control

Tags: c#, winforms, label, event-handling

I'm sure you're all aware of the fact that the Label Control has no KeyDown handler (and why would it?)... Anyway, I'm in need of a KeyDown handler for the Label Control and would appreciate any pointers/suggestions to get me started.

I've searched around but haven't found any info on creating my own Event Handlers for the Label Control. Can this be done is C#?

Thanks

Comment: j-t-s what is the end goal to this?  Since there is no input from the user, the only things i can think of is you trying to combine a keydown with some sort of mouse click or mouse hover.  Can you give more details?

Comment: The end goal is to capture the KeyDown event on a Label Control so that when the Label has focus, and the user is typing, the Label Control will update automatically. I cannot spoof a TextBox COntrol for this.

Comment: How can you type in a label?  Why not use a Textbox?

Comment: As Lily said, this will never be possible because the Label will not get the focus to receive the key presses from the user.  You will need to use a textbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did the following in the Constructor:

SetStyle(ControlStyles.Selectable, true);

and also override the OnMouseDown method:

```
protected override void OnMouseDown(MouseEventArgs e)
{
  base.OnMouseDown(e);
  if (this.CanSelect) this.Select();
}
```

After doing that your control should receive Keyboard events. But if you want to create a TextBox like control out of a label, it will be a lot of work...

Answer (score 3):

The problem starts far earlier. A label is not able to got a focus event. So it never has a focus and therefore never receives a `KeyDown` event.

If you really need something like that, you should spoof a `TextBox` with the following settings as starting point:

```
textBox1.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None;
textBox1.Cursor = Cursors.Default;
textBox1.ReadOnly = true;
textBox1.TabStop = false;
textBox1.Text = "foo";
```

Another possibility is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2309662/editable-label-controls/2310106#2310106).

Answer (score 1):

A Label isn't designed to receive input from a user, so as others have pointed out it cannot get focus or the Key* events.  If you did manage to get this working, it wouldn't be obvious to users because they cannot click on the label to give it focus to start typing.

Perhaps if you explain more what you're trying to achieve someone may suggest an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, `Label` inherits from `Control`, so it has a [`KeyDown`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc491269.aspx) event.  It's just that Visual Studio isn't showing it in the GUI, because `Label`s aren't intended to receive focus, so said event normally wouldn't fire.

Comment: That is true, thank you for reminding me! I have come up with a solution myself and will post the solution once I've finished testing it.